# Darin enthalten ist die Registrierung auf unserer Unternehmenswebseite,

Tags: grammar-identification

> Darin enthalten **ist** die Registrierung auf unserer Unternehmenswebseite,

How is the verb "ist" not in second posation?

source:
*Die Jahreslizenz bezieht sich nicht auf das Ausbildungsjahr, sondern auf das jeweilige Kalenderjahr. Darin enthalten ist die Registrierung auf unserer Unternehmenswebseite, der Nutzung der Filterfunktionen mit den Sie die anonymisierten Daten unserer Schüler/-innen selektieren können und der Zugang zu weiteren Features, die sie hinzu buchen können.*

Comment: Close voters: How on earth could this question be answered by a dictionary, thesaurus or conjugation table? Please explain.

Answer (score 6):

It is not the second word, but it is in second position, because you can't separate the "Darin enthalten" (you can reorder it though: "enthalten darin").

Another example:

> Das größte aller Tiere ist der Blauwal

Here `das größte aller Tiere` again is inseparable and forms one unit. So the verb is again in 2nd position.

Comment: Except that you can: „Darin ist die Registrierung auf unserer Unternehmenswebseite enthalten.“

Comment: Das ist aber eine andere Konstruktion, oder?

Comment: Darin enthalten ist zwar ein Partizip aber hier nicht in der Rolle des Perfekts, wie in deinem Satz. Aber für fehlt mir das genaue Wissen, das vermag bestimmt jemand anderes zu beantworten